# jQuery's problem with the position method

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following markup:

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  <div id="child" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

and I want to get the position of the child relative to its parent, would the only way be as follows?:

```
x = parseInt($('#child').css('left')); // returns 0 as needed
y = parseInt($('#child').css('top')); // return 0 as needed
```

Because if I do the following:

```
x = $('#child').position().left; // most likely will not return 0 
y = $('#child').position().top; // most likely will not return 0
```

the position is wrong due to the fact that the offset method does also add the margin, padding, and border of the grandparents (be it the body element with its default margins or any other grandparent element).

I need to get the right position (in my example it would be `0, 0`) but I suspect there is no method in jQuery that can calculate it for me?

Comment: A note: $('#child').css('top') can give "auto" if explicit top is not specified.

Answer (score 7):

`.position()` is correct. It'll give you the `x` and `y` values relative to an element's offset parent. Your `#child` element is positioned relative to its own offset parent, which is `<body>`. In order to make `#parent` its offset parent, give it a `position` of `relative` or `absolute`.

```
<div id="parent" style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <div id="child" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;...;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the document. 
Use .offset()